# How to remove curly braces from a namespace

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I would like to know how I can remove the braces from a namespace and have it be closed with a semicolon (;).

actually:

```
namespace ProductsGroup{
  public void save{
  }
}
```

I need:

```
namespace ProductsGroup;
  public void save{
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a specific refactor? (That may come, but C#10 is still new). Otherwise Visual Studio is a text editor...

Comment: Make sure your project language targets c# 10

Comment: c# 10 should add something like `using namespace x.y.z;` consistent with c++ and also the `using` statement in C# which dropped the braces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Visual-Studio 2022 already offers this refactoring (and the reverse).

Additionally you can set a preference in Visual Studio's C# Code Style settings, and in `.editorconfig`.

More details: https://www.ilkayilknur.com/how-to-convert-block-scoped-namespacees-to-file-scoped-namespaces

***Update***: **The above assumes valid code**

In the question you have:

```
namespace ProductsGroup{
  public void save{
  }
}
```

which *is not valid in any version of C#*.

Top level functions can be used, but not with a namespace (all top level functions end up in a class, named based on the filename, in the root namespace).

Otherwise you need a type. So you can refactor:

```
namespace MyNamename {
  public class MyClass {
    public Task MyAsync() {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

to/from

```
namespace MyNamename;
public class MyClass {
  public Task MyAsync() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is also trying to use a non-class scoped function, which isn't allowed, and might be part of their issues

Comment: @OneCricketeer updated answer to cover  invalid code in Q!